# Pass a parameter to Vue router meta title

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to create a dynamic title for a Vue route. It seems I cannot find a way to pass a parameter into meta title. I need it, because I have a `VueHeader` component, which renders a heading from route meta title. Here's my code:

```
  {
    path: '/case/:id',
    name: 'edit-case',
    component: VueEditCase,
    meta: {
      title: 'Edit case ' + $route.params.id,
    },
  },
```

However, I am getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $route is not defined`. Same happens if I have `title: 'Edit case ' + this.$route.params.id` or `title: 'Edit case ' + route.params.id` or `title: 'Edit case ' + this.route.params.id`. I've also tried `title: 'Edit case ' + ':id'`, etc.

I could not find any answer on the internet, so I am asking for your help here, guys. Anyone got some similar problem and solved it?

Here's an image of other, working, routes:
[image: working routes]

Here's an image of how I am rendering the meta title in header:
[image: header renderring from route meta title]

Here's how header looks when entered the respective example routes:
[image: route to dashboard]
[image: route to service items]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can help you, instead of importing meta title from router file, you can create it in your file.

`<h1>{{ "Case Detail " + $route.params.id }}</h1>`

[image: my html]

[image: output for me]

Edited for your condition which is a very specific one:

You can try one thing , if your Header Component is a different component you can pass id as a prop to it, so that it will be having id and render your dynamic title only when id is available and for Dashboard and Service Items you can put a condition when id is not available there

Comment: Sorry, but this is not going to work in my case. `VueHeader` component is a separate component and is being rendered from parent template, as well as the content.
If I would use this suggestion, I would end up with `Dashboard` and `Service items` having a header of "Case Detail ". I need to set the title in ***`router`.***

Comment: You can try one thing , if your `Header Component` is a different component you can pass `id` as a prop to it, so that it will be having `id` and render your dynamic title only when `id` is available and for  `Dashboard` and `Service Items` you can put a condition when `id` is not available there.

Comment: I was also thinking of doing something similar to this, but I expected to find some better, proper way. Just because there is no official way to achieve this in Vue documentation, I think I will just use this. Edit your answer so I can make it an "Accepted answer". And thank you for your help and effort!

Comment: happy to help you !!

Answer (score 2):

I was once trying to accomplish the same thing, but unfortunately, I think it is not possible. As [this guy says on GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3108#issuecomment-577066390), router's meta is intentionnally static.

If you are trying to make the document's `<title>` tag dynamic, I would suggest you to try [Vue-Meta](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta). I really love this plugin and use it on every Vue SPA project.

Answer (score 1):

i think this can help you, write this in `mounted hook` of the file

```
mounted() {
  document.title = "Edit Case " + this.$route.params.id
}
```

let me know if this worked for you as it did for me

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your effort. This is working, but this is not what I am looking for. This will only change the document's title tag to "Edit case XXXX". However, I am looking to set a route meta title. As I have mentioned, I am rendering a heading on header from route meta title, like this: 
`<h1>{{ this.$route.meta.title }}</h1>`
What you suggested will not solve the problem.

Comment: can you post an image of where that title is and what will it look after route changes

Comment: I've updated my question with images, as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set the meta value like follows,

```
this.$route.meta.title = "Your title";
```

In your case, you can watch the route changes from any of the parent component and set the meta value.

```
    watch: {
        // watching the route
        '$route': function () {
            // if params and id
            if (this.$route.params && this.$route.params.id) {
                this.$route.meta.title = "Your title " + this.$route.params.id;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [VUE META](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/guide/caveats.html#reactive-variables-in-template-functions), follow the doc to setup title on each component of views, so, in the component with params on url, add this code

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: () => {
        return "My title with params " + this.$route.params.my_param;
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

`metaInfo()` is a function of vue meta that you can use routes params to set any tag on head.

Answer (score 0):

try `this.$route` or

`console.log(window.location)` there and see how you can retrieve id from there

Comment: I can get an id from there, yes. But I need to pass an id to the route specified above, because I want to show a title saying "Edit case XXXXX". Any other routes I have without any parameter, work fine. Fx. `title: 'All cases'` will work fine, but it does not include a dynamic parameter.

Comment: i understood your question, for example your url is `case/123` you want to show your title as `Edit case 123`